# Can luatex export coordinates of "glyph boxes"?

Tags: luatex, shipout

Consider the following sample LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
Test $x^2$
\end{document}
```

When processed by one of the TeX engines, one gets a pdf with glyphs that are associated with boxes nicely put together by the shipout process (IIUC).

Say that the pdf page is a *canvas*. I'd like luatex to output a file with the coordinates of each glyph box in the cartesian coordinate system of the *canvas* (let's take the origin at the bottom left of the *canvas*).

Any ideas? (Maybe the `lua-visual-debug` package is a good starting point but I am not an expert in that field and I barely understand how it works traversing all page nodes).

The whole idea here is to let luatex build pages, paragraphs or formulæ and use a scriptable graphics editor like gimp or inkscape to actually draw on the *canvas* (in my use case, that would be blender but I don't think it matters).

Note that what I really need are the coordinates of the glyph *origin* (if that concept even exists!), that is where to draw the glyph on the *canvas* (the box is just the TeX way of seeing its output ignoring how the glyph are actually drawn, IIUC again).

Comment: Let's assume that you get a large file of coordinates of all the glyphs - from text, header, footer, floats, footnotes, marginpars, from normal chars, from accents, ligatures, math supscripts, from nominator and denominator of fractions, and other stuff. How will you identify the coordinate you are interested in?

Comment: there is a quite old answer of mine which does something similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213647/2891 - I don't expect it to work without modifications as LuaTeX change a lot in the meantime

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good point. I guess luatex could output the glyph "reference" to be drawn along with its coordinate origin.

Comment: @michal.h21 Really interesting. Thanks for the link. I need some time to dig and try to understand and maybe adapt to my needs.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464875/8425

Comment: I think dvisvgm can be useful here. But I haven't thought through the details.

Comment: `lua-visual-debug` just inserts whatsits to draw colorful boxes in the PDF.  It doesn't know about its position on the canvas either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Inspect the shipout box

What you could do is override the `\shipout` primitive to execute some custom Lua code which walks the vertical list and inspects the nodes.  This needs a fairly recent LuaTeX to be able to use `token.scan_list`.  I have not yet found out how to determine the starting position in a sensible manner, so all coordinates are relative to the lower left corner of the bounding box of the first glyph.  The coordinates are in `pt`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\directlua{
```

```lua
local mode
local x = 0
local y = 0
local glue = { hmode = 0, vmode = 0 }

local function glyph_boxes(head)
    for n in node.traverse(head) do
        if n.id == node.id"hlist" then
            mode = "hmode"
            y = y - n.shift
            glyph_boxes(n.list)
            y = y + n.shift
        elseif  n.id == node.id"vlist" then
            mode = "vmode"
            glue.hmode = 0
            glyph_boxes(n.list)
        elseif n.id == node.id"glue" then
            glue[mode] = glue[mode] + n.width
        elseif n.id == node.id"kern" then
            glue[mode] = glue[mode] + n.kern
        elseif n.id == node.id"glyph" then
            x = x + glue.hmode
            local c = string.utfcharacter(n.char)
            local f = font.getfont(n.font)
            print(c, f.name, x / 2^16, y / 2^16)
            x = x + n.width
            glue.hmode = 0
        end
    end
end

function shipout()
    local box = token.scan_list()
    tex.setbox(255, box)
    glue.vmode = 0
    print() % just for nice formatting
    glyph_boxes(tex.box[255])
    tex.shipout(255)
end
```

```
}

\def\shipout{\directlua{shipout()}}

\begin{document}
Test $x^2$
\end{document}
```

Output in the log:

```
T   [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;  0.0 0.11000061035156
e   [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;  6.3899993896484 0.11000061035156
s   [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;  10.830001831055 0.11000061035156
t   [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;  14.770004272461 0.11000061035156
x   cmmi10  21.990005493164 0.11000061035156
2   cmr7    27.705276489258 3.7389221191406
```

## SVG export

Another option to obtain glyph coordinates is using the `dvisvgm` driver.  This requires a bit more handwork but is in general less complex.  In that case the document is simply

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
Test $x^2$
\end{document}
```

Typeset using

```
dvilualatex test.tex # or simply latex
dvisvgm --font-format=woff --no-merge test
```

The log might contain some information about not being able to embed certain fonts.  This is irrelevant because we don't want to render the SVG but only extract data.  The `--no-merge` option prevents the driver from merging adjacent letters into a single XML entity.  I have removed the base64 encoded font data for brevity.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- This file was generated by dvisvgm 2.3.5 -->
<svg height='8.109622pt' version='1.1' viewBox='-72.000004 -72.000007 48.811833 8.109622' width='48.811833pt' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>
<style type='text/css'>
<![CDATA[
@font-face{font-family:cmr7;src:url(/* base64 data */) format('woff');}
@font-face{font-family:cmmi10;src:url(/* base64 data */) format('woff');}
text.f0 {font-family:cmmi10;font-size:9.96264px}
text.f1 {font-family:cmr7;font-size:6.973848px}
text.f2 {font-family:[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;;font-size:10px}
]]>
</style>
<g id='page1'>
<text class='f2' x='-72.000004' y='-63.890385'>T</text>
<text class='f2' x='-63.662905' y='-63.890385'>e</text>
<text class='f2' x='-54.498905' y='-63.890385'>s</text>
<text class='f2' x='-45.334905' y='-63.890385'>t</text>
<text class='f0' x='-32.853344' y='-63.890385'>x</text>
<text class='f1' x='-27.159412' y='-67.505749'>2</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

This is hopefully all the information you require.  You have the `class` for each letter which you can match to the respective font using the embedded CSS and the `x` and `y` coordinates on the canvas.  I cannot tell you where the origin is though.  The units are probably `bp`.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I was looking for! Thnaks!

Comment: May I ask you to elaborate a bit on what `token.scan_list` is actually doing. IIUC, it takes the argument of the original `\shipout` (which should be a box) and set `\box255` with its content. Am I right?

Comment: @cjorssen `token.scan_list` scans a box expression, i.e. `\box255`, `\namedbox`, `\hbox{...}` or `\vbox{...}`.  You can obtain recent LuaTeX for TeX Live from https://github.com/hmenke/texlive-luatex-dev

Comment: Why do you need token.scan_list? Can't you use atbegshi to parse the shipout box like eg lua-visual-debug does it?

Comment: @cjorssen I don't get such a message.  For me the above MWE processes fine.

Comment: @cjorssen I added another solution using SVG export.

Answer (score 3):

There is a special function for that in LuaTeX: `pdf.getpos()`, it gets coordinates right from the engine. In order to use it, you need to add a Lua whatsit to the shipout box.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
    function PrintPos()
        print(pdf.getpos())
    end
    function ProcessList(head)
        for n in node.traverse(head) do
            if node.is_glyph(n) then
                local printpos = node.new("whatsit","late_lua")
                printpos.data = PrintPos
                node.insert_before(head, n, printpos)
            end
            if n.head ~= nil then
                ProcessList(n.head)
            end
        end
    end
    function PrintCoordinates()
        local soBox = tex.getbox("ShipoutBox")
        ProcessList(soBox)
    end
```

```
\end{luacode}
\AddToHook{shipout/before}{\directlua{PrintCoordinates()}}

\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

It outputs:

```
5157309  49122001
5478085  49122001
5667536  49122001
5856987  49122001
6398072  49122001
7023118  49122001
7384798  49122001
7651752  49122001
7841203  49122001
30992932 7677017
```

The last coordinate is the page number. And... don't mess with the `shipout` routine and `box255`. Just add a hook and use `ShipoutBox`. Otherwise you can get just a partial output if you use packages like `scrlayer-notecolumn`. Also keep in mind that some packages can also have hooks for `shipout/before` and may discard the whole page.